# Setting coordinate system to many rasters in ModelBuilder?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, coordinate-system, modelbuilder

I have one digital elevation model and i need to divide it in many parts and set 
Lcoordinate system (UTM zones...)  for every part.

[image]

I have tried to make a model but i do not know, how to import the atribute with EPSG code(value) to function *project raster* like output coordinate system.

Comment: The help doc says it check the output coordinate system environment setting...however if you're dealing with more than one UTM zone, I don't think that will work. How many zones? Do you need to calculate which zone to use for each raster?